# After the call to notifyItemChanged, the adapter not get notified and the onBindViewHolder do not called

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, when I try to update a single item of the adapter. Making call to `notifyItemChanged`. It does not make any change. I attach the code.

I am using a component that to show a stack of missions, and in a certain percentage of swipe I need to show an approved icon, rejected at the top of the layout, I am managing to capture it but when updating the item recycler does not update it.

Fragment :

```
public class PushMissionsFragment extends BoostFragment implements PushMissionsAdapter.MissionCardListener, FavouriteListener {

@Inject
Navigator navigator;

@Inject
UserViewModel userViewModel;

@Inject
FinalUserViewModel finalUserViewModel;

@Inject
MissionViewModel missionViewModel;

@Inject
MissionRepository missionRepository;

@BindView(R.id.stack)
SwipeStack stack;

private PushMissionsAdapter adapter;

private Location myLocation;

private final FavouriteListener favouriteListener = this;

public static PushMissionsFragment newInstance(){
    return new PushMissionsFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getContext(),getBoostActivity());
    myLocation = gpsTracker.getLocation();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);

    adapter = new PushMissionsAdapter(getContext(), myLocation, this);

    final AdapterConverter<PushMissionsAdapter, PushMissionsAdapter.ViewHolder, Mission> adapterPRO = new AdapterConverter<>(getContext(), adapter);

    finalUserViewModel.getFinalUser(userViewModel.getUserId()).observe(this, new Observer<FinalUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable FinalUser finalUser) {
            if (finalUser != null){
                adapter.setList(finalUser.getAvailableMissions());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                stack.setAdapter(adapterPRO);
            }
        }
    });

    stack.setSwipeProgressListener(new SwipeStack.SwipeProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeStart(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeProgress(int position, float progress) {
            Log.d("PROGRESS", String.valueOf(progress));

            if (progress >= 0.5f){

                final Mission mission = adapter.getItemAt(position);

                mission.setAccepted(1);
                adapter.getList().set(position, mission);
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(adapter.getList().indexOf(mission));

            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {

        }
    });
    stack.setListener(new SwipeStack.SwipeStackListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewSwipedToLeft(int position) {
            if (adapter.getList() == null || adapter.getList().size() == 0)
                return;
            adapter.getList().remove(position == 0 ? 0 : adapter.getList().size() - position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewSwipedToRight(int position) {
            if (adapter.getList() == null || adapter.getList().size() == 0)
                return;
            String missionId = adapter.getItemAt(0).get_id();
            missionRepository.saveFavouriteMission(missionId, favouriteListener);
            adapter.getList().remove(position == 0 ? 0 : adapter.getList().size() - position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStackEmpty() {

        }
    });
    return view;
}

@OnClick(R.id.accept)
public void accept(){
    stack.onViewSwipedToRight();
}

@OnClick(R.id.cancel)
public void cancel(){
    stack.onViewSwipedToLeft();
}


@Override
protected int getViewId() {
    return R.layout.fragment_push_missions;
}

@Override
protected void injectDependencies(BoostComponents boostComponents) {
    boostComponents.inject(this);
}

@Override
public void onMissionClick(Mission mission) {
    if (mission.getCategory() == Mission.category.presential){
        if (mission.getContactPoints().size()==1){
            navigator.showFirstMissionStartActivity(this, mission, mission.getContactPoints().get(0).get_id());
        }else {
            navigator.showMissionPDVsActivity(this, mission.get_id());
        }
    } else if (mission.getCategory() == Mission.category.prediction){
        navigator.showFindMissionFormPredictiveActivity(getBoostActivity(), mission.get_id());
    }
}

@Override
public void onFavouriteSaved() {
    SyncroManager.setUploadScheduler(getContext(), userViewModel.getUserId());
}}
```

Adapter :

```
public class PushMissionsAdapter extends AdapterConverter.Adapter<PushMissionsAdapter.ViewHolder, Mission>{

private final Context context;

private final Location myLocation;

private MissionCardListener mListener;

private final List<Mission> list = new ArrayList<>();

public PushMissionsAdapter(Context context, Location myLocation, MissionCardListener mListener){
    this.context = context;
    this.myLocation = myLocation;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

public List<Mission> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(@NonNull final List<Mission> missionList){
   this.list.clear();
   this.list.addAll(missionList);
}

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public Mission getItemAt(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_push_missions, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v, mListener);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (list == null)
        return 0;
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Mission mission = list.get(position);

    holder.mission = mission;

    Glide.with(context).load(mission.getCardImageUrl()).into(holder.imagen);

    if (mission.getAccepted() == 1){
        holder.card_accepted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.card_accepted.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (mission.getCanceled() == 1){
        holder.card_canceled.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.card_canceled.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.marca.setText(mission.getBrand().getName());
    holder.donde.setText(mission.getPlace().toString());
    holder.descripcion.setText(mission.getDescription());
    holder.puntos.setText(Integer.valueOf(mission.getPoints().intValue()) + " PTS");

    if (!mission.getCategory().toString().equals("presential")) {
        holder.linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.imagen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.relative_predictive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.linear_predictive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.relative_predictive.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.linear_predictive.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Location mLocation = new Location("pdv");
        mLocation.setLatitude(mission.getContactPoints().get(0).getLatitude());
        mLocation.setLongitude(mission.getContactPoints().get(0).getLongitude());
        float distanceInMeters = myLocation != null ? myLocation.distanceTo(mLocation) : 0f;
        holder.distancia.setText("A " + (distanceInMeters == 0f ? "undefined" : Math.round(distanceInMeters)) + " Mts");
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder extends AdapterConverter.ViewHolder {

    private MissionCardListener cardListener;

    Mission mission;

    @BindView(R.id.imagenMision)
    ImageView imagen;

    @BindView(R.id.image_accept_card)
    ImageView card_accepted;

    @BindView(R.id.image_cancel_card)
    ImageView card_canceled;

    @BindView(R.id.marca)
    TextView marca;

    @BindView(R.id.donde)
    TextView donde;

    @BindView(R.id.descripcion)
    TextView descripcion;

    @BindView(R.id.puntos)
    TextView puntos;

    @BindView(R.id.linear)
    LinearLayout linear;

    @BindView(R.id.relative_predictive)
    RelativeLayout relative_predictive;

    @BindView(R.id.linear_predictive)
    LinearLayout linear_predictive;

    @BindView(R.id.distancia)
    TextView distancia;

    ViewHolder(View itemView, final MissionCardListener cardListener){
        super(itemView);
        this.cardListener = cardListener;
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.relative_predictive)
    public void onClickPredictive(){
        cardListener.onMissionClick(mission);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.imagenMision)
    public void onClickPresential(){
        cardListener.onMissionClick(mission);
    }
}

public interface MissionCardListener{
    void onMissionClick(Mission mission);
}
```

}

Comment: See if the size of the list you are setting in the adapter is non zero, also paste the relevant logcat

Comment: the recycler works fine the list non is zero, see the logcat  **D/put list size:: 1**

Answer (score 0):

Simply call

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
```

instead of

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(adapter.getList().indexOf(mission));
```